# O dicionário de parâmetros contém uma entrada nula

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, requisição

Estou com o problema que é o seguinte, estou consumindo um serviço onde ele recebe um parâmetro como entrada, no [frontend](/questions/tagged/frontend) eu mando esse parâmetro via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), mas ele retorna como erro e fala que não passei o parâmetro:

Frontend:

```html
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/api/Simplex/PostLinear",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: {"id": '1'},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
           alert(result);
      },
     error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
           alert(request.responseText);
      }
});
```

Backend:

```
 public class SimplexController : ApiController
{
    //PostLinear
    public string PostLinear(int id)
    {
```

e retorna essa mensagem:

> {"Message":"A solicitação é inválida.","MessageDetail":"O dicionário
>   de parâmetros contém uma entrada nula para o parâmetro 'id' de tipo
>   que não permite valor anulável 'System.Int32' para o método
>   'System.String PostLinear(Int32)' em
>   'TCC.Controllers.SimplexController'. Um parâmetro opcional deve ser um
>   tipo de referência, um tipo que permite valor anulável ou declarado
>   como opcional."}

Caso eu mude a *url* da requisição para `http://localhost/api/Simplex/PostLinear?id=`1 ele funciona, mas quero passar o parâmetro pelo data do ajax, como proceder?

Answer (score 1):

Passe o valor do id sem as aspas:

```
data: {"id": 1},
```

e anote a sua função:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostLinear(int id){
```